# dotnet SqlConnection InMemory support

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, .net-core, sqlconnection

I am trying to unit test my queries using an inmemory database.
My query is originally implemented using a SqlConnection, however for unit test purposes, I return a SQLiteConnection.
My issue is the differences in the two languages. While my SQL statement runs perfectly fine using the regular SqlConnection, stuff like temporary tables are not supported in the same way using SQLiteConnection, hence giving an exception.

```
await using var connection = _connectionProvider.GetConnection();

var accountToAutoCreate = await connection.QueryAsync<EntityDto>(Sql);

return accountToAutoCreate.Select(x => new Entity(x.Id));
```

Is there a way to either use an In Memory data source in the original SqlConnection or support SQL using a SQLite connection? I would rather not having to account for SQLite when writing my queries.

Comment: You can use a [LocalDb instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)